# Python string is not empty but they are empty cells in excel

Tags: python

I have some columns that contain text and blank cells. For example:

```
 a    b    c 
yes  no    yes
     no
no         no 
     yes   yes
```

I am trying to define a function to assign indicators, assign 0 to rows that are blank, assign 1 to rows that are not blank.

```
def ind(x):
    if x==" ":
        return 0
    else: return 1
```

The results give me columns of 1.. then I checked string that empty cells are not empty.

How can I make these empty cells empty and make this function work?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: We're going to need far more information than this. See: [ask], [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

By **Empty cells** I assume you mean excel cells that either do not contain any text, only whitespace or cells that do not contain anything at all. To consistently figure out which cells are "Empty"-

- Truncate the string using `strip()`
- Check whether the truncated string is `''` (i.e empty string) using `not` operator

```py
if not x.strip():
    # x is empty
```

More on `strip()` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Edit: Since in this case, the empty cells are being interpreted as `NaN` (i.e not a number), you can either try

```py
if x.strip().lower() == 'nan':
    # x is empty
```

or you can use `math.isnan(x)` from the inbuilt `math` module.

```py
if math.isnan(float(x.strip())):
    # x is empty
```

Comment: Yes, I mean the excel cells. I have checked by using the following codes,            
 def blnk(myString):
    if myString.strip():
        print("it's not an empty or blank string")
    else:
            print("it's an empty or blank string")                                                                             then it shows they are not empty. I am wondering how can I make the empty cells to be blank?

Comment: try printing `myString`, see what it exactly is for "empty" cells.

Comment: Empty cells are something like this: "                      NaN".  multiple spaces before Nan.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly